# Equivalent FXML attribute to ChangeListener?

Tags: javafx-2

I'm in the process of converting a JavaFX application from declaring/configuring its controls in Java code to splitting out the layout to an FXML config.  The problem I'm having is that I can't locate the equivalent attribute (?) to the code's ChangeListener.

In the original Java code, I have

```
    class TextFieldChangeListener implements ChangeListener<String> {
        private  boolean isRequiredDataPresent() {
            return outputNameTextField.getText().length() > 0 && numOfOutputFilesTextField.getText().length() > 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void changed( ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue, String s, String s2 ) {
            mergeButton.setDisable( ! isRequiredDataPresent() );
        }
    }
```

About the closest I can get using FXML is:

```
<TextField id="outputNameTextField" onKeyPressed="#textBoxOnChange" promptText="Path of merge file" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowSpan="1" />
```

The problem with using onKeyPressed is that it doesn't pickup pasted in values like ChangeListener does.  How do I add a change listener in FXML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not do that because the value property is a sub-part of TextField. So you have to write it in your code. FXML comes only for the graphical aspects.
For more information about FXML :

- http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm
- http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/jfxpub-fxml_get_started.htm

Comment: I guess I'm just confused as to why I can add a onKeyPressed event, but not an onChange event in the FXML.  It seems like I ought to be able to either do both, or do neither.

Comment: It's only because a change listener is not only a function but a listener on a property. It's the way of think of Java FX.

Comment: @PhilippeGeek The problem with JavaFX is it's diversity. You can listen to change events of CheckBoxes using onAction in FXML (although onAction is also a property). However, you cannot do the same with Spinners, TextAreas, and many others. I wish there would be a common super type "Field" for all those components that carry a value. And this super type should have an setOnValueChange method and a value property.

Comment: yep. disappointed too. WPF XAML is much more advanced compared to FXML